# Perron-frobenius theorem for Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

As I'm working on a concept in linear algebra, I want to know is there a perron-frobenius theorem for Hermitian matrices? I tried to find something on the web but I couldn't find anything.

Bests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest work that I know of which allows complex entries is: [Dubois, Projective metrics and contraction principles for complex cones](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/jlms/jdp008/abstract) (LMS, 2009), which is in turn inspired by [Rugh, Cones and gauges in complex spaces: Spectral gaps and complex Perron-Frobenius theory](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2010/171-3/p07), (Ann. Math. 2010).

If you instead meant a Perron-Frobenius theory over matrix valued variables, that is a separate topic treated elsewhere.